# Can “inverted” be used to indicate that something is "inside-out"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

If something is inside out, can it be said that the object is ***inverted***?

My understanding of the word ***inverted*** is simply "the opposite state," but I would like to get a bit of clarification just to be sure.

Comment: ***invert*** in a broad, general sense; ***evert*** in a more precise, technically correct way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The word you're looking for is **everted** ([turned inside out](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/evert)). Sorry if it's a bit stomach-churning, but [here are 884 written references](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22everted%20stomach%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) to *everted stomachs*. Surprisingly, most of them are nothing to do with dissected dead specimens - quite a few animals evert their stomachs to feed, including [starfish.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rE8l-KFQlhY)

*Inverted* can also mean inside out, but then it can mean 'swapped' in all sorts of other ways too.

Comment: +1 - I've never heard of the word before, but it certainly is helpful to know.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *inverted* can mean *inside out*: inverted balloon, inverted condom.

Answer (score 2):

"Inverted" seems better reserved for "upside down"; "everted" applies to something that is inside out.

Answer (score 0):

Inverted can also mean that something's state has been changed from the current state.

For example

> 1. Inverted transistor
> 2. Current Inverters, which changes the current flow direction.
> 3. Inverting a two-way jacket.

Comment: Doesn't your third example indicate that something has become inside out?

Comment: Yeah thats what I meant to say