# Is there a technical term for insideout-ness?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, hypernyms

So the technical term for right or left handedness is chirality.

The technical term for evenness or oddness is parity.

Is there a similar term for inside-out-ness vs right-side-out-ness?

EDIT:
I wish to speak of 2 objects. They have no interesting features except that each could be considered 'inside-out' relative to the other. Except there is no 'right' side. I suppose I could arbitrarily designate one side as Right and the other as In, but there are reasons to avoid doing so.

"Object 1 and object 2 differ only in their ***_***."

I tried both chirality and parity but neither fit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can “inverted” be used to indicate that something is "inside-out"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27231/can-inverted-be-used-to-indicate-that-something-is-inside-out) (the word is **everted**)

Comment: The term is inside-outness.  You already have it.  Also, chirality is a chemistry-specific term, so I think it is somewhat misleading to call it technical.

Comment: Oops - just realised OP wants a word to describe the existence of a distinction between "normal" and "everted". I can't cancel the vote to close, but I can say there are so few real-world referents it would stagger me if there's even a specialised scientific term for it. Bear in mind particle physicists co-opted *colour* and *spin* for similar contexts, where the original meanings are unrelated to the scientific ones. But those scientific differences are [probably] *real*, whereas OP's one probably isn't.

Comment: @z7sg Ѫ: If "inside-outness" were ever used, I'm sure most people would take it to mean "eversion". I can't imagine a context where it would mean "the distinction between whether a thing is normal or everted". Would you seriously say *"Can you check the inside-outness of my freshly-laundered socks"*, for example?

Comment: @FumbleFingers It gets a few hundred hits on google books.  I might say that.  I wouldn't say *"Can you check whether my socks are everted?"* because it's unlikely someone will know what that word means, fine word though it is.

Comment: @z7sg Ѫ: You're quite right in that people do sometimes use "inside-outness", but checking some of those google books entries it seems to me they always mean the attribute of *actually being inside-out*, not the distinction between whether that attribute is true or false.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I want to say "what is the ____ of your socks?" and get inside-out or right-side-out as the answer, but the context it formal and technical so inside-out-ness sounds silly.

Comment: @z7sg Ѫ: chirality is also used in math and physics with similar meaning.

Comment: @Matthew Scouten: I'd normally say *chirality* only and exactly means left/righthandedness (as in *shoes*). But if I was asked to normalise the chirality of a pile of socks, I think I'd understand. Though I'd certainly think the person asking me had some pretty odd ways of saying things!

Comment: Can you say more about what it is that you have that is "inside-out"? Maybe give an example of the usage of the purported word?

Comment: What's wrong with *handedness* instead of *chirality*? Anglo-Saxon words get no love from the sciences. That said, my vote is for side-outness.

Comment: Are you thinking of something like a pair of tanks made from sheet steel which are identical in size and shape but one has raised seams on the inside whilst the other has them on the outside?

Comment: @BenBold Actually, I was originally thinking of genitals. Someone had made a remark about sex differences involving more then just the *chirality* of one's genitals. I knew the word was wrong, but was not sure that the correct work would be.

Answer (score 9):

In [topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology), there is ["Orientability"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability), but I haven't studied it to know if it *is* the right term.

And there is the term ["eversion"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eversion#English), meaning "to turn inside-out", so the actual answer might be "evertedness", or just "everted".

Comment: We're definitely on the same page here! I considered *evertedness*, but I just thought *evertivity* might have useful echos of *parity*. On the other hand, there are probably more people who would accept that *evertedness* is "already" a word, even though if it's ever used it's probably in relation to "degree of eversion" rather than to distinguish "inside-out" from "inside-in".

Comment: Orientability is not the right term. But "orientation" can possibly fit; whether it does depends a bit on what the OP had in mind for the application.

Comment: To add to @Willie's comment, orientability is (very loosely speaking) the thing you need for the words "inside" and "outside" make sense.

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest "eversion"; I think this is a reasonable thing to put into your blank: "they differ only in their eversion".

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's an existing word, but for potential neologisms I'd suggest either **evertive orientation** or **evertivity**.

Thanks to @Dan Brumleve for suggesting **eversity**, which I think is an even better coinage, in that it resonates nicely with *parity* and *chirality*

Comment: evertivity is the best I have heard so far. googling pretty much leads back to this question :) –

Comment: @Matthew Scouten: Now I think further on it, it seems to me that theoretical physicists *ought* to have a word for the concept. I know it's not exactly what we're talking about here, but the possibility of the universe being [open/closed/flat/etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_Universe), or even being entirely contained inside a black hole within a different universe, could prompt them to create/find/use a word relevant to us here.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have seen such a word before, but I can not remember it.

Comment: Came here from math.SE to coin "eversity".

Comment: @Dan Brumleve: Way ahead of you, man! It's interesting to note that in the math.se page where I asked you guys for help, and in the one about turning shirts inside out that was flagged up to me there, the word *eversion* was actually used several times. But over here my two variants thereof have thus far collected the grand total of no votes whatsoever. But I'll tack your *eversity* in my answer if you don't mind - it resonates better with *parity*, which I think is a plus point.

Comment: @Dan Brumleve: as much as I like eversity as a word, it is taken (as eVersity) as a trademark.

Comment: @Matthew Scouten: I doubt the owners would sue us for infringement of copyright! :)

Answer (score 2):

The word "containment" may suit your needs.

Example usages

- The containment of the point is outside the box.
- The containment of this side of the fence is inside.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example provided in the initial question, it sounds like when both objects are in disparate states of eversion they are not enantiomorphs even though they may share a chiral form otherwise (e.g., a pair of gloves with one inside-out). Depending on the characteristics of those objects, when they are in the same state of eversion they may or may not be enantiomorphs as they may or may not be chiral (e.g., a pair of gloves versus a pair of tube socks). If one says that two objects differ only in their states of eversion, is that intended to signify that everting the non-everted one would result in a pair of enantiomorphs or that it would result in an achiral pair--or is the intention to refrain from such specification? I feel like that is where a lack of clarity in the initial question may have yet to be addressed.